# What did Roger Sterling do at the Pond’s lunch?

Tags: plot-explanation, mad-men

In Mad Men season 4, episode 2, *Christmas Comes But Once a Year*, Freddy Rumsen comes back to the agency, bringing with him the Pond’s account. Shortly thereafter Roger Sterling comes back from a lunch meeting with Pond’s, apparently drunk. Freddy Rumsen (who is a recovering alcoholic who has given up drinking) looks alarmed and calls up his contact at Pond’s to find out what happened. Peggy Olsen, seeing his alarm, asks what’s the matter. He says “put two and two together” and rushes out.

I can’t put two and two together. What happened between Roger Sterling and the Pond’s client at lunch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Freddy's contact at Ponds is Cal Rutledge who is also a recovering alcoholic. They are both members of Alcoholics Anonymous.

It's implied that, as a result of Cal having the lunch meeting with Roger, he lapsed and got drunk with Roger.

Freddy calls Cal to meet him at a church which reveals that Freddy is Cal's AA sponsor.